# step process with JavaScript doesn't change colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a step process with JavaScript.
And I want it when it reaches the step 3, the color changes to another color.
I tried a lot, but I didn't succeed.

Picture how step process works

[image: Picture how step process works (with three green blocks)]

Picture how I want it to work

[image: Picture how I want it to work (with two green blocks and a red block)]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;

  var id = setInterval(steps, 700);

  function steps() {
    if (i == 4) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      $(".step" + i).css('background-color', 'rgb(134 209 109)');
      i++;
    }
  }
  $(".btn-next").on("click", function() {
    $('.page-1').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('.page-2').fadeIn(1000);

    });

    var interval = setInterval(slide, 1200)
    d = 1;

    function slide() {
      if (d == 6) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $('.btn-next-two').fadeIn();
        $('.search').fadeOut();
      } else {
        $(".ship-" + d).addClass('slide-in-left');
        $(".ship-" + d).css('display', 'block');
        d++;
      }
    }
  });
  $(".btn-next-two").on("click", function() {
    $('.page-2').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('.page-3').fadeIn(1000);

    });
  });
  $('.btn-delivery').on('click', function() {
    $('.page-3').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('.page-4').fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
  $('.btn-time').on('click', function() {
    $('.page-4').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $('.page-5').fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
step {
  min-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #a9b7b9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2 col-sm-1  offset-2 offset-sm-4 step1 step">
</div>
<div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step2 step">
</div>
<div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step3 step">
</div>
<div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step4 step">
```

Comment: It's almost never right to add an event listener inside another event listener. Every time you click on `.btn-next`, it starts another interval timer and adds additional click listeners to the buttons.

Comment: Where are the buttons in the HTML?

Comment: The DIVs need a width so we can see the colors.

Comment: It works normally, just a page that loads it
But I want it when it loads a page and works, the color of the third step changes only

Comment: Can you update the HTML in the snippet so we can try to run it and see the results?

Comment: @Barmar I mean, I did it like an AJAX loading system
But through javascript, I hope an idea arrives

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point you're trying to make. It doesn't seem related to my comments.

Comment: Now I understand, you're saying that this code is supposed to display cycling buttons, like is frequently used while waiting for something to load with AJAX. But that has nothing to do with my comments.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like waiting. When it loads the page, it works and automatically reaches a third step. I just want when it reaches a third step, I put a color that is different from the first and second step, as shown in the picture that has a red color

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a tiny issue in your javascript code.

I updated the function step.

```
function steps(){
  if(i == 5){
    clearInterval(id);
  }
  else if(i == 3) {
    $(".step"+i).css('background-color','red');
    i++;
  }
  else{
    $(".step"+i).css('background-color','rgb(134 209 109)');
    i++;
  }
}
```

Here is full code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i = 1;

      var id = setInterval(steps,700);
      function steps(){
           if(i == 5){
               clearInterval(id);
           }
           else if(i == 3) {
               $(".step"+i).css('background-color','red');
               i++;
           }
           else{
               $(".step"+i).css('background-color','rgb(134 209 109)');
               i++;
           }
      }
      $( ".btn-next" ).on( "click", function() {
      $('.page-1').fadeOut(1000, function(){
          $('.page-2').fadeIn(1000);

      });

      var interval = setInterval(slide,1200)
      d = 1;
      function slide(){
          if(d == 6){
              clearInterval(interval);
              $('.btn-next-two').fadeIn();
              $('.search').fadeOut();
          }
          else{
              $(".ship-"+d).addClass('slide-in-left');
              $(".ship-"+d).css('display','block');
              d++;
          }
      }
      });
      $( ".btn-next-two" ).on( "click", function() {
      $('.page-2').fadeOut(1000, function(){
          $('.page-3').fadeIn(1000);

      });
      });
      $('.btn-delivery').on('click',function(){
       $('.page-3').fadeOut(1000, function(){
          $('.page-4').fadeIn(1000);
          });});
      $('.btn-time').on('click',function(){
       $('.page-4').fadeOut(1000, function(){
          $('.page-5').fadeIn(1000);
          });});
      });
```

```css
.step{
  min-height:20px;
  margin-right:2px;
  border-radius:14px;
  background-color:#a9b7b9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1  offset-2 offset-sm-4 step1 step">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step2 step">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step3 step">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1  step4 step">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the "tiny" issue, and how did you fix it? Don't make us compare the two codes to see the changes.

Comment: Exactly well done as it is but I want when it reaches step 3 the color changes to red

Comment: There is only one line change.
           if(i == 5){
               clearInterval(id);
           }
Okay, I will try that part too.

Comment: Do you want to change all divs to red when it reaches step 3?

Comment: @toptecshare Yes, exactly. I just want a third line to be in a different color, red color

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
else if(i == 3){
           $(".step"+i).css('background-color','red');
           i++;
       }
```

on the condition.